# Añadir una columna a la sección clientes backoffice prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Estoy intentando añadir una columna en el backoffice de prestashop versión: 1.6.1.1 dentro de la sección clientes.

La columna que estoy intentando añadir es 'dni' del cliente que se pide en el registro de usuarios en mi tienda.

He intentado añadirla con el siguiente código en controller/admin/AdminCustomerPreferencesController.php:

```
      $this->fields_list = array(
        'id_customer' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('ID'),
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Social title'),
            'filter_key' => 'a!id_gender',
            'type' => 'select',
            'list' => $titles_array,
            'filter_type' => 'int',
            'order_key' => 'gl!name'
        ),
        'firstname' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('First name')
        ),
        'lastname' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Last name')
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Email address')
        ),
        'dni' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('dni')
        ),
    );
```

Pero al incluir esto me da el siguiente error:

Consulta SQL incorrecta
Unknown column 'dni' in 'field list'

He buscado por ahí pero sólo encuentro como añadir columnas personalizadas nuevas pero yo necesito el dni que ya viene en el proceso de registro.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La columna o campo DNI forma parte de la tabla de dirección (`ps_address`), no de la tabla de cliente (`ps_customer`). Para incluirla en un controlador de *admin* tendrias ademas que agregar un `LEFT JOIN` a la consulta para la obtención de los datos, para poder obtener ese campo en el `SELECT`.